# item within versionoverrides invalid 'webapplicationinfo' on Exchange on prem with Azure AD Hybrid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchange-server-2016

We have a working outlook app using version 1_1 on O365. We are testing this with an exchange on prem only setup but with azure AD hybrid. The graph API functions we need work within this environment thanks to testing on graph api exporer.

When we push the manifest to exchange either via the exchange admin portal or via powershell we receive an error relating to webapplicationinfo being invalid. We have this within versionoverride 1.1 and that within versionoverride 1.0

If I remove the webapplicationinfo section which includes the scope, this will import ok, but when the app performs the function to get the auth token it fails, for which I am sure because the scope wasnt authorised.

No where i can find that says on prem is not supported. I find a lot of reference to 2016 CU3 but nothing specific to on prem. Can someone assist?

Comment: Do you have any problems with O365 tenant? Do you still get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2016 Cumulative Update 3 (CU3), released in September 2016 for Exchange on-premises servers, adds support for REST API integration with Microsoft 365. If your app uses v1.0 of the Mail, Calendar, or Contacts API, you will now also find a seamless authentication and application experience in hybrid deployments, regardless of whether the mailbox is on-premises or in the cloud, provided that the deployment meets specific requirements.

See [Use REST APIs to access mailboxes in Exchange hybrid deployments (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support) for more information.

Comment: This references hybrid. Exchange is not in hybrid configuration. From what I can see our exchange is on cu22 and still errors.

Comment: Yes this works fine on the tenant hosting the app which has o365 and another tenant (multi tenancy) also on o365. A third tenant which is not on o365 but as mentioned above using azure ad hybrid (on prem dc with azure) and a on prem only exchange which fails as mentioned above.